# GameCenter iTunesConnect - Leaderboard is not a member of a leaderboard set attached to version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FQhzhM8.png]
[image: htt]

Does anyone know what does this mean?  I've tried searching everywhere but can't find a word on it.

Essentially I created a group for an app (and its deluxe counterpart), then created some leaderboards and added them to leaderboard sets.  Then I tried adding the leaderboard sets and checking their constituent leaderboards.

Unchecking all the leaderboards doesn't fix this and toggling off Game Center doesn't help either.

I can no longer save changes to the app and Apple hasn't gotten back to me (2 weeks).  I do have a default leaderboard selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it's just been resolved by iTunes engineers.  I'd recommend checking if it works on your end now too.

Answer (score 0):

From how I saw itunesconnect behaves w.r.t. leaderboard groups, I have seen that if there is any game that has leaderboard sets, any leaderboards that you add further (to that game) must be added to one of those sets only.

It doesn't allow you to add a leaderboard (that's not part of any group)  to the same game.

**Perceived Rule:** There is no place for standalone leaderboards once you create a set.

**What might be happening in your case:**

Since you have created a group for your group of games - probably your other app (game) is having some standalone leaderboards. Since you added them first, it allowed you to add them as standalone. After coming to second game, you created a set, and since all leaderboards (MUST) belong to the sets - and sets to the game group - this is iTunesConnect's way of complaining.

**Solution:**

Go to other game belonging to the same group (Group Reference Name) and delete those standalone groups, or maybe make them part of a set. Save. Then come back to this game and check those leaderboards again.

Maybe I am not right about your other game, but I am sure there are orphan leaderboards that are no part of any sets that's causing the problem.

Comment: This was an interesting idea.  I've added another app to the gamecenter group to test it out.  

Without adding any leaderboard sets (although the leaderboards are all part of sets) it saved just fine.  So I suspect the issue is with leaderboard sets somehow. As far as I can see, I have no orphan leaderboard anywhere.

For the apps I actually want to modify, it won't let me remove or add anything at this point (the red text makes me feel like Apple is angry).    I get one of these guys: http://i.imgur.com/FQhzhM8.png

Comment: have you tried attaching every group to the app under the Versions page? Maybe click them, check them, anything to make sure it's "Added" in whatever way Apple thinks right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no dice, I actually can't even change a single thing about the app right now (Apple is taking their time!).  It gives me the error no matter what, though I will be a sad antelope if I do indeed need to add every set to each group member.

Comment: The only thing that remains (from the error message) I guess is the version dilemma - what you see under Versions page. Is there any version discrepancy between what you do under Game Center page vs Versions page?

Comment: Well I haven't altered the version numbers ever.  But this gave me the idea to delete the app from the group and try readding it.  Of course it seemed to work.  But I still had all the leaderboards added and couldn't remove them.  When I refreshed the group page, lo the apps were still there.  Spooky.   I looked for the ghost category in Apple's support page but it seemed to be missing too.  Conspiracy?  Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed with iTunes and I had to wait a few weeks for them to resolve it. It seems this is pretty common so for anyone else with a similar problem in the future I would essentially assume it's iTunes' fault and get in touch with Apple.  But don't expect it to be resolved quickly.